Number of divisors bound $ \tau(n) \leq 2 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \right)^{\pi(2^{1/\varepsilon})} \cdot n^{\varepsilon}. $
Let $0 < \varepsilon < 1$. Prove that the number of divisor $\tau(n)$ of a positive integer n
$$
\tau(n) \leq 2 \cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \right)^{\pi(2^{1/\varepsilon})} \cdot n^{\varepsilon}.
$$
Hint: For a prime $ p $ and a positive integer $ k $, $0<\varepsilon <1$ prove that
$$
\frac{k+1}{p^{\varepsilon k}} \leq \begin{cases} 
\left( \varepsilon e \ln p \right)^{-1} p^{\varepsilon}, & \text{for every prime } p, \\
1, & \text{if } p^{\varepsilon} \geq 2.
\end{cases}
$$
I am having trouble with the last part. I have already proven the hint. Then I define two sets of primes based on the above cases:

Set $S$: Primes where $p_i^{\varepsilon} \geq 2$.
Set $T$: Primes where $p_i^{\varepsilon} < 2$.

Let $t_T$ be the number of primes in $T$. Note that $t_T \leq \pi(2^{1/\varepsilon})$ Therefore, the primes in $T$ are all less than $2^{1/\varepsilon}$.
$$
\tau(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{t} (k_i + 1) = \prod_{i \in S} (k_i + 1) \cdot \prod_{i \in T} (k_i + 1).
$$
$$
\tau(n) \leq \left( \prod_{i=1}^{t} p_i^{\varepsilon k_i} \right) \cdot \left( \prod_{i \in T} \dfrac{p_i^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon e \ln p_i} \right) = n^{\varepsilon} \cdot \left( \prod_{i \in T} \dfrac{p_i^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon e \ln p_i} \right)=  n^{\varepsilon}\dfrac{1}{(\varepsilon e)^{t_T}} \cdot \prod_{i \in T} \dfrac{p_i^{\varepsilon}}{\ln p_i}.
$$
However, since $p_i^{\varepsilon} < 2$, we have $p_i^{\varepsilon} \leq 2$. Thus, $p_i^{\varepsilon} \leq 2$ for all $i \in T$.
Also, for all primes $p_i \geq 2$, $\ln p_i \geq \ln 2$, so I used that $1/(e \ln2)<1$
Therefore:
$\tau(n) \leq n^{\varepsilon} \cdot \left( 2 \cdot \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon} \right)^{\pi(2^{1/\varepsilon})}.$
The problem is that that factor 2 should have exponent 1 and I don't see how I should have achieved that. What should I do?
